# Polymer no output

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, google-web-component

I'm trying to learn Polymer, but I can't make it to work.

The new elements that I created are not showing any output other than the DOM elements

Kindly check my codes below:

Index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="dom-element.html">
    <link rel="import" href="hello-world.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <dom-element></dom-element>
    <hello-world></hello-world>
  </body>
</html>
```

dom-element.html

```
<link rel="import"
      href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="dom-element">

  <template>
    <p>I'm a DOM element. This is my local DOM!</p>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "dom-element"
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

hello-world.html

```
    <link rel="import" 
      href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" />
<polymer-element name="hello-world" noscript
    <template>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

here is the output:
I'm a DOM element. This is my local DOM!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dom-element looks fine and I have tested in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/URLRxbmn16q1lxF7tYKX?p=preview0). It works.
You hello-world uses Polymer 0.5 syntax. `polymer-element` was renamed to `dom-module` in 1.0 as described in the [migration guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#registration).

Comment: Thanks, now that's what I'm missing. This is my first question here in stackoverflow, thanks for the help.